# what are class_setIvarLayout and class_getIvarLayout?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to dynamic create objc class at runtime and I need to add some `Ivar` to the created class. I found `class_addIvar` which should do what I want, but I also found these functions:

- `class_setIvarLayout`
- `class_getIvarLayout`
- `class_getWeakIvarLayout`
- `class_setWeakIvarLayout`

the doc did not really said any useful information about these methods and I can't find out any useful explanation from web. So what are they? Do I need to use them if I want to do something with `Ivar`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `class_*IvarLayout` methods are used by the garbage collector (if/when you're using it) to determine which areas of an object's memory need to be scanned for strong/weak references.

It's unlikely you'll ever need to call these methods; the appropriate layouts are generated when you call `objc_registerClassPair`.